# imul dx with negative numbers produces large positive numbers in EAX?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

```
; test.asm  

segment .bss
extern  _a, _b, _x, _y

segment .text
global  _compute
_compute:

    mov ax,[_a]
    mov dx,[_x]
    imul    dx
    mov dword[_y],eax

    mov ebx,[_b]
    add dword[_y],ebx

    ret
```

There is no problem when calculating positive numbers, but when calculating negative numbers, the results look strange, such as "65544" and "65542." How shall I do it?

Comment: What inputs gave you 65544, and where is the code you used to print that or how did you know the result was 65544?

Comment: reading the docs it seems like the one operand 16 bit  imul stores the 32bit result not in EAX, but in DX:AX which I assume means that half of it is in DX, and the other half in AX

Comment: @PeterT This is correct.

Comment: If, per your title, this is to be called from C, note that in most calling conventions, `ebx` is a call-preserved register and you must return with it having the same value it initially had.  You would need to either push/pop it, or else choose a different register that is call-clobbered.

Answer (score 4):

The 16-bit form of one-operand `imul` leaves the product in `dx:ax`, not in `eax`, even in 32-bit mode.  It matches the behavior from 16-bit 8086 which had no 32-bit registers.

So you could do

```
    mov ax, [_a]
    mov dx, [_x]
    imul dx
    mov [_y], ax
    mov [_y+2], dx
```

But in 32-bit mode it may be nicer to sign-extend your 16 bit operands to 32 bits, and then do a non-widening 32-bit multiply (two-operand `imul`).  16-bit instructions are awkward because they need operand-size prefixes, and because they leave the high 16 bits of the 32 bit registers intact, potentially leading to performance problems because of the dependency.  So another choice is something like

```
    movsx eax, word [_a]
    movsx edx, word [_x]
    imul eax, edx
    mov [_y], eax
```